# database work flow analysis

Tags: database, oracle11g, analytics

I have analyzed my as below and I have two point I am confused about

1- currently when I insert an items within orders I give `order_ID`  as a `PK`
so each item within the order as its own `PK`... and same customer_id `(FK)` for all Item within the order so ... in that case the invoice number is same as the customer_ID

Is that what should think goes on or there is something wrong with this work flow ?

2-in some cases I don't need to record the customer information I just want to
insert the orders without their customer info.. I don't have clear idea about how think should happen :S

3- IF I want to apply a discount on some customer orders where the discount should I allow user to able to apply on the item per orders level ?
or on the whole order ? and where the discount column should be stored

[image: Database structure]

Answer (score 1):

1 - This design seems fine for the problem. You are stating that for every product ordered, this is the customer line. You can pick the ID, name, tax/fiscal number, address, etc.

2 - If you don't need any kind of customer information, make the customer_id on the Orders table accept NULL. It is the cleanest way to do it.

If for some reason NULLs are not an option or you want to keep on the database some basic anonymous customer data, you can create a line on customers for anonymous users (Ex.: ID: 1 / Name: ANONYMOUS ...) and place that ID on the order line.

3 - Placing the discount per product ordered might be the better idea.

- If you want to apply a discount for the complete order, you just need to place that discount on every single order line.
- If you want to apply a discount for a single product, you just need to place that discount on that product line.
- If you want to apply a discount for a single product with a limited ammount of quantity (Ex.: Discount of 50% but limited to 1 purchase), and the customers buys more than that limit, you just need to place 2 orders for the same product. One with the discount and max quantity and the other without discount and the rest of the quantity.

Placing this on the order level wouldn't work for single product discounts.

This were answers to your questions. I would also question your design in points like:

1. If the customer changes address, is your order supposed to change too? If not, you should use the normal approach for orders, which is to have a **order header** table, with fixed information, like the address and the foreign key to the customer, and a **order line** table, like your orders line, but with a foreign key to the order header. That also avoids repetition.
2. Are you expecting up to 2 phone numbers? If you do, the design is ok. If you don't know how many phone numbers to expect, maybe a table with phone numbers, with foreign keys to the customer might be a better approach.

Comment: I do not think leaving customer_id null is a good idea and about creating anonymous customer its also as work around to leave customer id null but still better than leaving customer id null
I was thinking about adding a colmun "Customer_type" to distinction between customer types who I want their personal info to stored or not
but I dont if this approach is better...

Comment: yes you are right aplaying discount on order leave and thats will lead to data repetition which will make the second
approach better... for last point Thanks i was not thinking about it

Comment: answers for your questions

If the customer changes address, is your order supposed to change too 
no, because this inforamtion about the customer it self not the shiping orders addres... please If you dont mind to give me more
explantion for that point ... which one their advantges is that fixed information will not be repete for with each order 
I totally I agree with you about that ..

Comment: second actually i don't know how many phone number my user need to store ... so I make two column and one of the should be proved
like ... your suggestion is 100% should be applied to my database design ... thanks but now I have to work on the interface design to allow users to add as much as they wont phone number

Comment: @samer If you are talking about creating a **customer_type** on the order table, that is a bad idea since it is related to the customer itself. That column should be on the customer table. Leaving the customer_id as NULL or with a key to a DEFAULT user is up to your implementation.

Comment: @samer When I talked about the address change, I was talking about after the order is delivered. If you want to extract information about delivered orders (Ex.: How many orders have I received per city, state or country? That could be helpful if I was to choose the location a new store/warehouse to open, to optimize routes / storage, etc.)
If the address is on the customer instead of the order, that kind of information wouldn't be precise since the address might not be the address where the order was delivered.

Comment: good point you mention thanks .. one last question we have missed to talk about...  since each item has its own **order_id** as **PK** that's would not be useful to give an invoice number (ID) to recognize specific invoice and if I used the customer_ID as invoice number I think that not good idea cause  if i am selling a customer who has an account so all his invoice number which will make that number useless for the same customer.... so should I make third column for invoice number and keep that number static for orders purchased by same invoice ?

Comment: You can do that (Create an invoice number column in orders), but it will be repeated throughout the orders, like the customer and date are. If you have columns that will be repeated, it would be a better idea to create a **order header** table with that info (Customer, Invoice number, Address, etc.) and keep the orders table as a **order line** table.

**Order line:** `Order Line ID (PK), Order Header ID (FK), Product ID (FK), Quantity, Unit Price, DIscount ...`
**Order header:** `Order Header ID (PK), Customer ID (FK), Invoice Number, Address, Zip Code, City, Country ...`